# Compare Two Rows and Update Start and End Dates

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need some help and I know I am not the only one to deal with this issue but I am wondering if you might have some ideas on how to handle the situation of comparing two rows of data filling out start and end dates.

To give you some context, we have a huge hierarchy (approx 8,000 rows and about 12 columns wide) that is updated each year.  Sometimes the values change and sometimes they don’t.  When the values don’t change, then I don’t need to adjust the dates.  When the values do change and a new row is added, I need to change the data.

I have attached some fake data to try and illustrate my data.  I am building this in MS Access, so I think this is more of a DBA type question that is going to be manipulated via a recordset type method.

In my example I have two tables – Old Table and New Table.  In each table there is a routing code field that represents my join field and primary key for this table.
The Old table represents existing data - tblMain.  The New Table represents the data to be appended - tblTemp.

To append the data, I have an append query set up in Access.  I perform a left join between the Old and New tables, joining on every field and append the rows that are null in the Old table. That’s fine and that is not where my issue is.

What is causing me issue is how to fill out the start and end dates.
So as you can see from my tables, we are running a zoo.  Let’s just say for the sake of the argument, our zoo started off pretty simple and has become more sophisticated.  We now want our hierarchy to expand out and become a bit more detailed as we are now capturing the type of animal (Level 4) and the native location (Level 5).

As you can see when comparing one table to another the routing codes are the same, so the append query has to have a join on each field.  When you do this, you return the Result Table which is essentially the Old and New tables stacked on top of each other.  You might think about a Union query but this is going to give me duplicates and I don’t want that.

If you notice in the Result Table there is a Start and End Date.  Let’s just say I get the start and end dates via message box that pops up upon the import of the data and is held in a variable.  I think there are dates in my real data but still trying to verify this.

So how do I compare (pseudo code for the logic needed)?
•   For each routing code:

- Compare Levels 1-5
       If the routing code is the same but Levels 1 -5 are not the same
             fill out the end date of the old record
             fill out the start date of the new record

This idea of comparing two records and filling out a data is quite prevalent in my organization but I haven’t found a way of creating the logic that consistently works so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Old Table
[image: Old Table]

New Table
[image: New Table]

Result Table
[image: Result Table]

Comment: UNION does not allow duplicate records, UNION ALL does. Really should give fields more informative names than Level1, etc. Similar name fields usually indicates a non-normalized data structure. If you set compound index, duplicate combinations will not be allowed. Exactly what determines date values? Sounds like need a VBA function to accomplish with recordset as you already recognize. When you have some code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: I totally appreciate the comments and agree.  That said, I am looking for ideas in how to get started with handling my issue so I appreciate your input/feedback and will take that into consideration.